# Laravel Attach Role using Select Box

Tags: mysql, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

i'm trying to attach role for user using select box but it doesn't work

i've Roles table and bridge table between Roles and Users Table

i know it's many-to-many relationship and i should use check boxes instead of select box

but at the time for some reason i need to assign only 1 Role for user

So, i have to use select box

Any ideas?

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'name'         => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'          => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'          => 'required|string|min:8',
    ));
    $password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->save();

    if ($request['user']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','user')->first());
    }
    if ($request['editor']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','editor')->first());
    }
    if ($request['admin']) {
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name','admin')->first());
    }

    return redirect('users')->with('success', 'user is successfully saved');
}
```

View

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-12">Roles</label>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name=admin" id="example-radio1" value="admin">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio1">Admin</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name=pharmacy" id="example-radio2" value="editor">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio2">Editor</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-5">
                                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name=company" id="example-radio3" value="user">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-radio3">User</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think checkboxes might be better here instead of individual radio inputs.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="admin"><label>Admin</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="editor"><label>Editor</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="user"><label>User</label>
```

On the Laravel side:

```
// find the ids of the roles submitted by name
$role_ids = Role::whereIn('name', $request->input('roles', []))->pluck('id');
// attach any ids needed
$user->roles()->attach($role_ids);
```